# Modifying object inside array with useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I've been having trouble using React's useContext hook. I'm trying to update a state I got from my context, but I can't figure out how. I manage to change the object's property value I wanted to but I end up adding another object everytime I run this function. This is some of my code:

**A method inside my "CartItem" component.**

```
const addToQuantity = () => {
    cartValue.forEach((item) => {
      let boolean = Object.values(item).includes(props.name);
      console.log(boolean);
      if (boolean) {
        setCartValue((currentState) => [...currentState, item.quantity++])
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
```

**The "Cart Component" which renders the "CartItem"**

```
  const { cart, catalogue } = useContext(ShoppingContext);
  const [catalogueValue] = catalogue;
  const [cartValue, setCartValue] = cart;

  const quantiFyCartItems = () => {
    let arr = catalogueValue.map((item) => item.name);
    let resultArr = [];
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      resultArr.push(
        cartValue.filter((element) => item === element.name).length
      );
    });
    return resultArr;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {cartValue.map((item, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <CartItem
            name={item.name}
            price={item.price}
            quantity={item.quantity}
            id={item.id}
          />
          <button onClick={quantiFyCartItems}>test</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

So how do I preserve the previous objects from my cartValue array and still modify a single property value inside an object in such an array?

edit: Here's the ShoppingContext component!

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const ShoppingContext = createContext();

const PRODUCTS_ENDPOINT =
  "https://shielded-wildwood-82973.herokuapp.com/products.json";

const VOUCHER_ENDPOINT =
  "https://shielded-wildwood-82973.herokuapp.com/vouchers.json";

export const ShoppingProvider = (props) => {
  const [catalogue, setCatalogue] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [vouchers, setVouchers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCatalogueFromApi();
    getVoucherFromApi();
  }, []);

  const getCatalogueFromApi = () => {
    axios
      .get(PRODUCTS_ENDPOINT)
      .then((response) => setCatalogue(response.data.products))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  const getVoucherFromApi = () => {
    axios
      .get(VOUCHER_ENDPOINT)
      .then((response) => setVouchers(response.data.vouchers))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <ShoppingContext.Provider
      value={{
        catalogue: [catalogue, setCatalogue],
        cart: [cart, setCart],
        vouchers: [vouchers, setVouchers],
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ShoppingContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

edit2: Thanks to Diesel's suggestion on using map, I came up with this code which is doing the trick!

````
   const newCartValue = cartValue.map((item) => {
     const boolean = Object.values(item).includes(props.name);
     if (boolean && item.quantity < item.available) {
       item.quantity++;
     }
     return item;
   });
   removeFromStock();
   setCartValue(() => [...newCartValue]);
 };```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have access to both the value and the ability to set state here:

```
const addToQuantity = () => {
    cartValue.forEach((item) => {
      let boolean = Object.values(item).includes(props.name);
      console.log(boolean);
      if (boolean) {
        setCartValue((currentState) => [...currentState, item.quantity++])
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
```

Now... if you do `[...currentState, item.quantity++]` you will always add a new item. You're not changing anything. You're also running `setCartValue` on each item, which isn't necessary. I'm not sure how many can change, but it looks like you want to change values. This is what `map` is great for.

```
const addToQuantity = () => {
    setCartValue((previousCartValue) => {
      const newCartValue = previousCartValue.map((item) => {
        const boolean = Object.values(item).includes(props.name);
        console.log(boolean);
        if (boolean) {
          return item.quantity++;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
      return newCartValue;
    });
  };
```

You take all your values, do the modification you want, then you can set that as the new state. Plus it makes a new array, which is nice, as it doesn't mutate your data.

Also, if you know only one item will ever match your criteria, consider the `.findIndex` method as it short circuits when it finds something (it will stop there), then modify that index.

Comment: Nice idea on the map!! But it seems to be taking up a lot of memory. I've tried doing mapping inside a setState before and it usually crashes my app. I've implemented this code and it seems to be working right now!!

```
const addToQuantity = () => {
    const newCartValue = cartValue.map((item) => {
      const boolean = Object.values(item).includes(props.name);
      console.log(boolean);
      if (boolean) {
        item.quantity++;
      }
      return item;
    })
    setCartValue(() => [...newCartValue]);
  };
```